# Why did I only receive reviews from reviewers 3 and 4?

Tags: peer-review, elsevier

I have recently received reviews for my manuscript from Elsevier.
There are comments from Reviewer #3 and Reviewer #4 only, does that mean reviewer 1 and 2 rejected the article??

Comment: Ask the editor.

Comment: More likely turned down the invite to review or did not respond.

Comment: Alternatively: the reviewer backed out after being sent the paper. I'm pretty sure my current paper in the review process had that happen. It went out for review and ended up with a different reviewer after just a couple of weeks.

Comment: If a reviewer has rejected your paper, their comments are probably the most important, as those would be the comments blocking your paper from being published.

Comment: Reviewer 1 was on holiday and reviewer 2 did not make the deadline due to covid infection

Comment: We’re just speculating, but another possibility is they sent a short response that’s not relevant to the author like “Looks interesting and at an appropriate level for the journal, but I’m too busy to write a report, maybe ask X, Y, or Z?”

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most likely they did not respond to the reviewer invitation, or accepted it but did not submit a review in time. The system still logs them as reviewers #1 and #2.

Answer (score 2):

For most journals two reviews is standard, so as the others noted it's likely Revs. 1 and 2 did not submit a review at all, probably because they either forgot or didn't feel like they had sufficient expertise in the subject matter.